# How to write test cases for the following method that holds the local object return by the database?

Tags: java, testing, mockito, testng, powermockito

Currently, I am using TestNG and try to write the test case for the 
manipulateMetaData() method. Inside that method, metaData is given by the repository. And then the metaData is updated according to the given list of contact.

I stuck while writing the test case for manipulateMetaData() method.

```
public class MetaData {

    String email;
    Map<String, Integer> count = new HashMap<>();

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    public void updateCount(List<String> contact) {
        // perform the calculation and update the count.
    }
}

public class MetaDataHandler {

    @Autowired
    MetaDataRepository metaDataRepository;

    public MetaData manipulateMetaData(String emailAddress, List<String> contact) {
        MetaData metaData = metaDataRepository.findOneByEmail(emailAddress);

        if (metaData == null) {
            metaData = new MetaData();
            metaData.setEmail(emailAddress);
        }

        metaData.updateCount(contact);

        return metaData;
    }
}
```

TestCase

```
@Mock
MetaDataRepository metaDataReporitory;

@InjectMocks
MetaDataHandler metaDataHandler = new MetaDataHandler();

@BeforeMethod
public void setUp() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

@Test
public void testManipulateMetaData() {
    List<String> contact = new ArrayList<>();

    String emailAddress = "someone@gmail.com";

    Mockito.when(metaDataReporitory.findOneByEmail(emailAddress)).thenReturn(null);
   //Stuck Here
   //Want to test manipulateMetaData() method
}
```

Comment: This code looks wrong `metaData.updateCount(List<String> contact);`  should be `metaData.updateCount(contact);`

Comment: Thanks. Now i corrected the question.

Comment: where are you stuck? whats exact thing you are looking for?

Comment: I first mock the metaDataRepository to return the null value. Then call the manipulateMetaData() method from the test method. After than I don't know what to do?

Comment: please show your test class

Comment: Updated current test method.

Comment: are you writing test case for manipulateMetaData() method?

Comment: did you got solution ?

Comment: Yes, changing little bit of system architecture by removing the metaData.updateCount(contact); from above method.

Answer (score 0):

Mockito.when(new MetaData().thenReturn("your mocked object")));

This will help you, please google more

Comment: Basically I don't get how to handle  metaData.updateCount(contact); while writing test case for that method.

Comment: hey ..  metaData.updateCount(linklist<String> contact)

Comment: updateCount() changes the internal state of metadata. But As you can see  it doesn't return anything.

Comment: How to perform Mockito.when(metaData.updateCount(contact);).thenReturn(1);  from test method.

Comment: is it ok if you use powermockito?

Answer (score 0):

!!

are you using maven also if yes then you should give the dependencies in prom.xml

you have to pass email address and custom list while making test case  and pass that value to the fuction while writing the  jUnit test case .

```
String email="xyz@yahoo.com"; //your email custom here you can take value from scanner also just declare the scanner object and take value from user .
List<String> contact  = new LinkedList<String>; //declaration of linklist 

//now write code here to take some value from the user (like we normally take some value and insert it into the list )
//once list value is inserted do ...

Metadata meta_test = null ; // take obj of metadata as you have made a return type 

meta_test= manipulateMetaData(email, contact); //call that function 

//if return we get is null that means nothing is inserted in meta_test and it must show red while testing and if not null that means test case is successful :)

 if(meta_test != null)
 {
    asserttrue(true);
 }
 else
 {
   assertrue(false);
 }
```

//hope, I solved your problem , I may not be specific in term od syntax in some place ..srry for that :)

Comment: How to handle  metaData.updateCount(contact); ? while writing testcase.

Comment: test case for same function can also be made :)
also try not to make the void type function . make the return type of that function mostly Boolean , 
and check if the return type is true or not . you can make the test case in another class same like the comment above :)

Answer (score 0):

See in unit testing you test the behavior of your code unit. Here I assume you are writing a test case to check the behavior of `manipulateMetaData()` when `metaDataReporitory.findOneByEmail(emailAddress)` returns `null` and you expect `manipulateMetaData()` will create a new record with email address and updateCount.

so far you have successfully  mocked `metaDataReporitory.findOneByEmail(emailAddress)`. next steps should be:

- call the manipulateMetaData() eg. 
  `Metadata metadata= metaDataHandler.manipulateMetaData(emailAddress ,contacts);`
- now check what did manipulateMetaData() actually do, Assert some
  checks:

  assertEquals(metadata.getEmail(), emailAddress);
- you can also verify the calls on the mock objects:

  verify(mock, atLeastOnce()).metaDataReporitory.findOneByEmail(emailAddress);

for more test Scenario see [this](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Mockito/article.html#mock-object-generation)